# signing a JWT with a .pfx file

Tags: azure, jwt, certificate, pfx

I need to acquire an access token from Microsoft using [their certificate flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#second-case-access-token-request-with-a-certificate).

I think it should be something very similar to what was explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59216430/how-can-i-sign-a-jwt-to-exchange-an-access-token-from-azure-active-directory) post, but I was only given a .pfx file from the person who set up the tenant app in the Azure Account.
If I try to follow the steps, I am asked to "enter import password" - which I don't know.

Is there anything I can do from my side to sign a JWT token using this .pfx file?

edit: I'm using Java, with the Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL).

Comment: 1/2) You need to know the password to use a PFX (PKCS#12) file as the contents are encrypted. Your goal is to use OAuth Confidential Client Assertion. Microsoft provides libraries that make this very simple, otherwise you will need to base64 the certificate hash and sign the JWT with the private key. Edit your question with details on the language, runtime and if you want to use a library or hand crafted code. For c# this article shows both the simplest method and how to hand craft the code: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-client-assertions

Comment: 2/2) Don't forget to upload the public key (.cer) to Azure AD first.

Comment: Is there any solution to sign the jwt with pfx in java? Did you figure out sth?

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing something like this -

**Step 1: Load the Certificate**

```
object CertUtil {
  private val DIGEST_ALGORITHM = "SHA-1"
  private val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12")

  def loadCertificate(certLocation: String, pwdLocation: String): Certificate = {
    keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(new File(certLocation)), readPassword(pwdLocation).toCharArray)
    keyStore.getCertificate(keyStore.aliases().nextElement())
  }
```

**Step 2: Create a client_assertion**

Client Assertion is a jwt signed with your certificate's private key and used by AAD Server to perform identity check of your request before issuing the token.

```
def createJWTToken(aadURL: String, clientId: String, scope: String, key: Key, certThumbPrint: String): String =
  Jwts.builder()
    .claim(Claims.AUDIENCE, aadURL)
    .claim(Claims.ISSUER, clientId)
    .claim(Claims.SUBJECT, clientId)
    .claim(Claims.ID, UUID.randomUUID.toString)
    .claim(Claims.EXPIRATION, NOW + ONE_HOUR)
    .claim(Claims.NOT_BEFORE, NOW)
    .setHeaderParam(X5THUMBPRINT, certThumbPrint)
    .signWith(key)
    .compact()
```

**Step 3: Create Post Payload using Client Assertion Token**

A Payload containing the clientId, Scope, GrantType, Client Assertion to be submitted to AAD Service in a url-encoded form.

```
def getPayload(request: AADRequest): String = {
  val token = JWTCreator
    .createJWTToken(
      aadURL(request.tenentId),
      request.clientId,
      getScope(request.appId),
      CertUtil.getPrivateKey,
      CertUtil.getThumbPrint
    )
  Map(
    (CLIENT_ID, request.clientId),
    (SCOPE, getScope(request.appId)),
    (GRANT_TYPE, GRANT_TYPE_VAL),
    (CLIENT_ASSERTION_TYPE, CLIENT_ASSERTION_TYPE_VAL),
    (CLIENT_ASSERTION, token))
    .map(_.productIterator.mkString("="))
    .mkString("&")
}
```

**Step 4: Invoke Azure AD Post API**

```
private def aadURL(tenentId: String) = s"${BASE_URL}${tenentId}${PATH}"

private def getScope(appId: String) = s"api://${appId}/.default"
def getAADToken(request: AADRequest): Future[String] = {
  CertUtil.loadCertificate(request.certPath, request.pwdPath)
  doPost(toPostRequest(aadURL(request.tenentId),
getHttpEntity(request)))
    .flatMap(response => Unmarshal(response.entity).to[String])
    .map(s => mapper.readValue(s, classOf[AADResponse]).accessToken)
}
```

**EDIT**

Maven Dependencies -

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-module-scala_${scala.version.major}</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.akka/akka-actor -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
      <artifactId>akka-actor_2.12</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.akka/akka-stream -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
      <artifactId>akka-stream_2.12</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.akka/akka-http -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
      <artifactId>akka-http_2.12</artifactId>
      <version>10.2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
      <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
      <version>0.11.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
      <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
      <version>0.11.1</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
      <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
      <version>0.11.1</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Can you update your answer to include the libraries required and the language version plus other details required to build the code?

Comment: I have updated the dependencies required.